# Inserting an iframe or Dynamic content into an info window?

Tags: google-maps, iframe, google-fusion-tables

I have a google map which is hooked up to a fusion table. Its pretty basic, lists street address, phone, and branch #.

I recently got a request though to add current weather to the info window that appears when a user clicks on a map marker.

Initially I thought I could just iframe this in, but it appears that google strips that HTML out of the info window when I add it in. I guess only basic html is allowed.

Does anyone know a way to throw dynamic content into that info window box or a way to get around google stripping out the iframe code?

Comment: What does your code look like? I assume you are talking about the default infowindow for a FusionTablesLayer. You should be able to add your own infowindow with whatever content you want.

Comment: Here's a direct link to the page: view-source:https://www.anixterpowersolutions.com/site/map.aspx

I tried opening the fusion table up and that section where you edit what the info window has on it but it seems to strip out the <iframe src=""></iframe> I've got some basic html in there that seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

The only iFrames I can get to work in fusion table map windows or cards are youtube embeds. Other iframes appear to get srtipped out as you say. It would be a good feature to be able to have universal iframe content instead of just google products.